# como solucionar el error IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

estoy tratando de crear un bot en discord que lo que hace es generar las 5 placas de cada usuario de habbo hotel pero en mi caso me tira el error indexError: en el caso de que el jugador de habbo hotel no tenga esa placa colocada en su perfil

Aquí muestro mi código a ver si alguien me puede echar una mano

```
import urllib
import json
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import io
 
from urllib import parse, request
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFile

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help  
    
        @bot.command()
    async def keko(ctx, *, HabboNombre):
            response = requests.get(f'https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users?name={HabboNombre}')
            habbo1 = response.json()["selectedBadges"][0]["code"]
            habbo2 = response.json()["selectedBadges"][1]["code"]
            habbo3 = response.json()["selectedBadges"][2]["code"]
            habbo4 = response.json()["selectedBadges"][3]["code"]
            
            habbo5 = response.json()["selectedBadges"][4]["code"]
            placa4 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get("https://images.habbo.com/c_images/album1584/" + habbo5  + ".png").content)).convert("RGBA")
            placa4  = placa4 .resize((40,40), Image.ANTIALIAS)#tamaño del keko 2
            url = "https://images.habbo.com/c_images/album1584/" + habbo1  + ".png"
            img1 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)).convert("RGBA")
            img1 = img1.resize((40,40), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    
            url1 = "https://images.habbo.com/c_images/album1584/" + habbo2  + ".png"
            placa1 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(url1).content)).convert("RGBA")
            placa1  = placa1 .resize((40,40), Image.ANTIALIAS)#tamaño del keko 2
            url2 = "https://images.habbo.com/c_images/album1584/" + habbo3  + ".png"
            placa2 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(url2).content)).convert("RGBA")
            placa2  = placa2 .resize((40,40), Image.ANTIALIAS)#tamaño del keko 2
            url3 = "https://images.habbo.com/c_images/album1584/" + habbo4  + ".png"
            placa3 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(url3).content)).convert("RGBA")
            placa3  = placa3 .resize((40,40), Image.ANTIALIAS)#tamaño del keko 2
            img2 = img1.copy()
            img1 = Image.open(r"keko.png")
            img1.paste(img2,(20,195), mask = img2) #mover la placa
    
            img1.paste(placa1 ,(70,195), mask = placa1)#mover la placa
    
            img1.paste(placa2 ,(120,195), mask = placa2)#mover la placa
            img1.paste(placa3 ,(170,195), mask = placa3)#mover la placa
    
            img1.paste(placa4 ,(220,195), mask = placa4)
            with io.BytesIO() as image_binary:
                 img1.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
                 image_binary.seek(0)
                 await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename='keko.png'))
             
    
    bot.run('')
```

Imagen del error en cmd:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias antemano!

Ejemplo: del usuario que no publica x placa .iroke.

cantidad de placas: 5

Comment: Pues parece que el api no te devuelve scinco badges, solo te envía 4.

Comment: Ya, no lo publica, es lo que quiero intentar pero no se como hacerlo en el caso que no este la imagen que me lo publique

Comment: Podrías agregar a tu pregunta la imagen que esperas que el bot envíe a Discord, un nombre de usuario para probar y la cantidad de placas que puede tener un usuario de Habbo porfavor?

Comment: Y pregunta? Todos los usuarios tienen 5 placas o algunos pueden tener más y otros menos?

Comment: Maximo son 5 placas por usuario

Comment: Entonces puede haber usuarios que tienen menos placas?

Comment: Y podrías agregar la imagen del que si funciona por favor? Para saber cual es el resultado esperado.

Comment: Si, en este caso el usuario .iroke. tiene 4 placas en su perfil, pero el bot no me lo publica y da ese error esta es la imagen que uso para agregar las placas https://i.imgur.com/4slaSWT.png

Comment: este usuario contiene las 5 placas. sefos y si funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Aclaración

No se bien como funciona el json que estás obteniendo ni el sistema de placas de Habbo (que segun Wikipedia se llama así ahora).
Sin embargo, intentaré ofrecerte una solución.

Analizando tu código, me di cuenta de las siguientes cosas.

- La ubicación de cada placa en el eje x se basa en la siguiente ecuación `20 + 50*numero de placa`, mientras que se colocan a la misma altura en el eje y.
- Te conviene usar un bucle for

A continuación intentaré explicarte los distintos elementos que se usarán en la solución.

#### Bucle for

En lugar de hacer cada imagen una por una, te recomiendo usar un [bucle for](https://j2logo.com/bucle-for-en-python/).
Por si el link se cae en el futuro, dejaré una cita de la pagina:

> El bucle for se utiliza para recorrer los elementos de un objeto
> iterable (lista, tupla, conjunto, diccionario, …) y ejecutar un bloque
> de código. En cada paso de la iteración se tiene en cuenta a un único
> elemento del objeto iterable, sobre el cuál se pueden aplicar una
> serie de operaciones.
>
> Su sintaxis es la siguiente:
>
> ```
> for <elem> in <iterable>:
>     <Tu código>
> ```
>
> Aquí, elem es la variable que toma el valor del elemento dentro del iterador en cada paso del bucle. Este finaliza su
> ejecución cuando se recorren todos los elementos.

Sabiendo todo esto, podríamos decir que no hace falta copiar un código una y otra vez, nos alcanza con un bucle for que vaya ejecutandolo. Y lo mejor de todo! No importa la cantidad de placas que haya, no ocurrirá ningún error por el hecho de que haya más o menos de lo esperado, o incluso ninguna.

#### función enumerate

Imagina que tenemos un iterable al que llamaremos it. Para saber la posición de cada item de it, podemos valernos de la función [enumerate](https://micro.recursospython.com/recursos/la-funcion-enumerate.html). enumerate devuelve un objeto el cual contiene tuplas. Cada tupla tiene el formato (inicio de la cuenta + indice del elemento de it, elemento de it).
enumerate acepta un segundo argumento que es desde donde empezar a contar. Por default esta función cuenta desde 0.

Por ejemplo `list(enumerate("abc", 2))` nos devolverá `[(2, "a"),(3, "b"),(4, "c")]`.

#### unpacking

El [unpacking](https://ichi.pro/es/que-es-desempaquetar-en-python-100958194683469) nos permite guardar cada item de un iterable en una respectiva variable. Por ejemplo `a, b = (1, 2)` hará que a valga 1 y b valga 2. Es posible usar el unpacking en un bucle for!!!

#### Solución

El siguiente código debería de solucionar tu problema sin importar el numero de placas del usuario. O si tiene placas en lo absoluto.

```
import urllib
import json
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import io
 
from urllib import parse, request
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageFile

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") #Comando
bot.remove_command("help") # Borra el comando por defecto !help  
    
@bot.command()
async def keko(ctx, *, HabboNombre):
    response = requests.get(f'https://www.habbo.es/api/public/users?name={HabboNombre}')
    selected_badges = response.json()["selectedBadges"]
    img1 = Image.open(r"keko.png")

    for index, badge in enumerate(selected_badges):
        placa = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get("https://images.habbo.com/c_images/album1584/"+badge["code"]+".png").content)).convert("RGBA")
        placa = placa.resize((40,40), Image.ANTIALIAS)

        img1.paste(placa, (20+50*index, 195), mask=placa)
        
    with io.BytesIO() as image_binary:
         img1.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
         image_binary.seek(0)
         await ctx.send(file=discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename='keko.png'))
     

bot.run('El token del bot de prueba')
```

Como habrás notado, este código es más claro y corto, además de resolver tu problema.

Produce lo siguiente en Discord:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la solucion 

Comment: Es un placer c: